# CSS not loading

Tags: asp.net, rendering

I have added a css file on my page. But sometimes. the css file doesnt load and the page renders in Normal HTML style. If we refresh the page manually then it loads. This issue is intermittent for all the browsers. Is there any solution for this. Can we ensure that the css loads every time before the page renders?
Thanks,
Rohit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this issue a lot in web development and there seems to be no solution as far as I know. Even sites like YouTube and gmail will sometimes not load the CSS leading to the page being rendered in a jumbled fashion with a white background. If it seems to only happen on your site, try switching hosts; maybe that will help.

Good luck!

Edit: the only reason I don't think this is code related is because you said it happens intermittently. Have you tried testing on numerous machines, not just different browsers?

Comment: Yes, I tried this on different machines as well. Is there anything we can do using jQuery or Javascript? Can we stop loading of the page untill the css loads? Not sure if this is the correct approach

Comment: @rohit we cant do that becoz browser load css after loading the page in other word browser send request for all <link> tag after getting html page

Comment: Do you know why it happens? I wonder if it's from CSS, HTML or it's related to the host.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put the style reference in `<head>` section of html and make sure the css markup are correct.

Style reference

```
<link href="SiteStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load dynamically with JQuery

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("head").append("<link>");
    css = $("head").children(":last");
    css.attr({
      rel:  "stylesheet",
      type: "text/css",
      href: "/css/stylesheet.css"
    });
});
```

Or this one

```
 $(document).ready( function() {
    $("head").append("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.css' />");

   });
```

you can use this trick also not good but may be work

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("style").load("css/style.css")
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior of the browser. Actually the browser caches the css file. But there is one way, you can do this, and that is to pass a query sting value as follows...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="http://www.domain.com/css/abc.css?v=1.1" />
```